# Access KeyVault with Subject Name + Issuer Auth

Tags: adal, azure-keyvault

I'm switching my AAD app over to Subject Name + Issuer auth and I believe I've done that correctly because I can get a token with my test app, but I don't understand how I can use SN+I to connect to KeyVault. The constructor for `Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets.SecretClient` takes a `TokenCredential` but none of the derived classes seem obviously related to SN+I auth. I'm not sure how to proceed with this scenario. Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gotten this scenario to work by creating my own "SniTokenCredential" class that inherits from TokenCredential. It retrieves a token like this:

```cs
IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_applicationId)
    .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{_tenantId}")
    .WithCertificate(_certificate)
    .Build();
AuthenticationResult authResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(requestContext.Scopes)
    .WithSendX5C(true)
    .ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Then I can return an AccessToken like this:

```cs
return new AccessToken(authResult.AccessToken, authResult.ExpiresOn);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a `ClientCertificateCredential` constructed with `ClientCertificateCredentialOptions.SendCertificateChain = true`. It [will include x5c header in client claims when acquiring a token to enable subject name / issuer based authentication for the ClientCertificateCredential.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/c54394ffe1c255aee1b3fec421a047be38254474/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/src/ClientCertificateCredentialOptions.cs#L19)